# SoundCloud help. Apple Mach-O Linker Error, "no such file or directory libJSONKit.a"

Tags: ios, soundcloud

I am building an app using the SoundCloud iOS SDK and Im trying to set up the necessary libraries. I have been following the Soundcloud tutorial but I didn't set up through a repository I instead downloaded the necessary zip files from github directly. I cannot find "libJSONKit.a", "libSoundCloudAPI.a", "libSoundCloudUI.a", or "libOHAttributedLabel.a".
Any help would be greatly appreciated thank you!

Comment: need more info-what actually did you do?

Comment: I added them to Link Binary With Libraries but they appeared red right after I selected them. I retried doing it with a git repo but that didnt work either.